# Hibernate annotations, autoincrement related

Tags: hibernate

i am using hibernate annotations, at the back end i am using Postgres SQL 8.3. So, i don't know how to apply sequence in annotations of my Class.

Plz provide related help for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
```

Then, put this in front of your sequence field:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

hope that was of any help...

Answer (score 4):

You can have more control over the generated sequence by implementing it like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="YourGeneratorName")
@GenericGenerator(
        name="YourGeneratorName", strategy="seqhilo",
        parameters={
                @Parameter(name="max_lo", value="1"),
                @Parameter(name="sequence", value="seq_name_of_the_sequence")
            }
)
private Long id;
```